# how to lint or prettier a json file with vscode in alphabetical order

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, lint, prettier, alphabetical

i have translation object and I want prettier to lint my keys in alphabetical order.

is there a plugin for that?

Comment: `lint` and `prettier` are 2 different things, `prettier` is a formatter

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74281875/836330